# How OS schedules threads on multiprocessors?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduler

I know that Linux CFS that has multiple processors have multiple queues each other like below.
[image]

Every times Queue migrates for balance(`work stealing`).
On above picture, unit in queue is `process`.
I  understood so far.

But I don't know how they work on multithread.
According to above picture, one process was assigned one cpu.
But as you know, multithread program works on multiple cpu.
All threads are created from only one process, how can each thread be assigned to multiple cpu?

How do they work, and how does thread context switching happen on multiple processors?

Comment: I don't know for certain about the state of Linux today, but in principle, processes are not "scheduled" or "assigned to CPUs." _Threads_ are scheduled to run on CPUs, and a process merely is a container for the resources that are needed by one or more threads.